# Remove margin on floated elements

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I'm working in a simple grid system and right now I'm facing a problem with floated columns. I use a 12 columns grid and all my columns have a left margin that I set with this selector: `[class*='column'] + [class*='column'] { margin-left: 1.6%; }`. The problem is that columns that doesn't fit in the same line are moved down but still preserve the margin, as you can see in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvmxhdp0/).

In this example I have a grid defining three four columns wide divs, one six column wide div and an eight column wide div. As the last two of them don't fit, they are displaced but not aligned as the have a margin. What can I do in this case to remove the margin?

Comment: Flexbox is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
[class*='col-'] {
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
[class*='col-'] +[class*='col-'] {
    margin-left: 1.6%;
}
.row, [class*='col-'] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row:before, .row:after {
    content:" ";
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
.col-4 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 32.2666666667%;
}
.col-6 {
    background-color: green;
    width: 49.2%;
}
.col-8 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 66.1333%;
}
#d6{
    margin:0%;
}
#d8{
    margin:0%;
}



and then your html:


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div class="col-4"></div>
    <div id="d6" class="col-6"></div>
    <div id="d8" class="col-8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately that's not an option as I want to do it for any combination. It's for a grid system.